# Port no in Oracle Forms 11G

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g

1. Which port number to be used in forms 11G Preference-->Runtime--> Application ServerURL Section?   I have:

   - 1521-Given at the time of database creation
   - 7003 and 7004-Given at the time of WLS Domain creation
2. Is it necessary to save the Forms before compiling or running the forms in browser?  If yes, then, is there any fixed location were I have to save it or I can save it anywhere and run it from that location?